# How to compute statistics (sum, mean, variance, etc.) over an entire dataset in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Computing mean, total, etc. of each feature in a dataset seems quite trivial in `Pandas` and `Numpy`, but I couldn't find any similarly easy functions/operations for [`tf.data.Dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset). Actually I found [`tf.data.Dataset.reduce`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#reduce) which allows me to compute running `sum`, but it's not that easy for other operation (`min`, `max`, `std`, etc.)


So, my question is, is there a simple way to compute statistics for `tf.data.Dataset`? Moreover, is there a way to standardize/normalize (an entire, i.e. not in batch) `tf.data.Dataset`, especially if not using `tf.data.Dataset.reduce`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, my question is, is there a simple way to compute statistics for tf.data.Dataset?

It depends on the statistics you wish to compute.

For instance, to compute the minimum or maximum, you can use:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(10, output_type=tf.float32) # sample dataset

minimum = ds.reduce(np.Inf, tf.math.minimum) # 0.0
maximum = ds.reduce(-np.Inf, tf.math.maximum) # 9.0
```

This is because [`tf.data.Dataset.reduce`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#reduce)'s requirements for the reduce function are directly met by minimum and maximum.

To compute the mean (and perhaps other statistics), one approach is to use [Keras metrics](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics). The code gets a bit messier, but it does the trick:

```py
mean = tf.keras.metrics.Mean()
for batch in ds:
    mean.update_state(batch)

print(m.result().numpy()) # 7.0
```

To compute statistics other than the ones available in Keras, I guess you'll have to write your own reducer function. For instance, if you wish to implement a reducer for the standard deviation, you can [calculate it](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1362467) based on a previous stddev and the new mean.

> Moreover, is there a way to standardize/normalize (an entire, i.e. not in batch) tf.data.Dataset, especially if not using tf.data.Dataset.reduce?

No, this is not possible since the elements in a `tf.data.Dataset` are not necessarily known until when you generate them.

Comment: You can calculate mean by ds.reduce(0., tf.math.add)/ tf.cast(ds.cardinality(),tf.float32)